# Sharp corner curved background image

Tags: html, css

been thinking of what would be the best way to achieve a background image with a sharp corners. I tried some css like `border-radius` and `clip-path` but no luck. I guess `clip-path` is the nearest possible answer but can't get it. Please see my sample below.

```css
.main-header {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/150x150') no-repeat center center;
  background-position: 0% 33%;
 background-size: cover;
  min-height: 480px;
  border-radius: 0 0 45% 45%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
<br>
</div>
```

I'm looking to have below image.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach?
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pabilag/edit?html,css,output)

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-header {
  background: url('http://www.stevensegallery.com/g/400/200') no-repeat center center;
  background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
  min-height: 480px;
  position: relative;
}

.main-header::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  /* You can play around with these numbers to adjust the curve */
  bottom: -4rem;
  left: -25%;
  width: 150%;
  height: 400px;
  border-bottom: solid 4rem white;
  border-radius: 0 0 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it works just edited the some values to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

if you can use image by img, not background. I think you can try "clip-path" as below.

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/astomusic/pen/rmQRpe)

HTML:

```
<div class="main-header">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
img {
        -webkit-clip-path: circle(100% at 50% 0);
        clip-path: circle(100% at 50% 0);
    }
```

and this site is useful to make clip-path (http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Comment: This is near but can't replicate it

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for it

Add `border-bottom-left-radius:60% 30%; border-bottom-right-radius:60% 30%;` css. You can play with radius properties to know how it works..

```css
.main-header {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/150x150') no-repeat center center;
  background-position: 0% 33%;
 background-size: cover;
  min-height: 480px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:60% 30%;
  border-bottom-right-radius:60% 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-header">
<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thanks, but I've played t he values it using border-radius and didn't get my sample image above.

Comment: I changed the values to `55% 5%` and it looked okay.

Comment: Hey thanks, but I wanted to achieve the corners same as the image I attached.